# Query in SQL Server 2008 not working in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
DECLARE @MyDate Datetime 
set @MyDate = GETDATE();
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT @MyDate AS AllDates,
       1 AS [count_all_days],
       CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, - 1, @MyDate)) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [count_week_days]
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd, - [count_all_days], @MyDate), 
       [count_all_days] + 1,
       CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, - [count_all_days], @MyDate)) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN [count_week_days] + 1 ELSE [count_week_days] 
       END
FROM cte
WHERE [count_all_days] - [count_week_days] < 16 
)

SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, AllDates))
FROM cte left join EmpLog ON AllDates = EmpLog.Date 
           left JOIN Holiday ON AllDates = Holiday.HolDate
WHERE DATENAME(dw, AllDates) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')AND AllDates NOT IN (Select EmpLog.Date from EmpLog where EmpLog.EmpID = 1)and Holiday.HolDate IS NULL
```

This SQL query displays the current date and the previous 16 days. wherein those dates are not equal to the existing date on the HOLIDAY table and in the `EMPLOG` table.

My problem is this query works on SQL Server 2008 well but when I tried it on SQL Server 2005 it only displays the current date and the previous 16 days even though some days are in HOLIDAY and `EMPLOG` table.

Can someone help me please? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try casting your Date variables -- you're comparing GetDate to Dates that don't necessarily have the same time:

```
left JOIN Holiday ON CAST(AllDates as Date) =  CAST(Holiday.HolDate as Date)
```

Wrap that with all your dates and it should work.  Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b320e/6).  In this example, I've only added 1 holiday, 1/21/2013 (MLK).

EDIT --

Try using `convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)` to `CAST` the `date` since SQL Server 2005 doesn't support the `Date` type.

Here is the updated SQL:

```
left JOIN Holiday ON convert(varchar, AllDates, 101) =  convert(varchar, Holiday.HolDate, 101)
```

Do that on all your date conversions.  Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b320e/8).

Thanks @user148298 for pointing this out.

Good luck.

Comment: SQL 2005 doesn't support Date.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: You can CAST that as any date...  Try using convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)

Comment: when i tried that code i get an error `Type Date is not a defined system type.` so i change the Date to Datetime but when i execute the query it sill displays the Holiday date.

Comment: sorry for late reply. yes i see your edited query. i'll try it first.

Comment: @sgeddes since i have 2 joins in my select statement EMPLOG and HOLIDAY, i also try your solution to the other join: `left join EmpLog ON convert(varchar, AllDates, 101) = convert(varchar, EmpLog.Date, 101)
                left JOIN Holiday ON convert(varchar, AllDates, 101) = convert(varchar, Holiday.HolDate, 101)` 

but when i execute the query the output still displays the date in the EMPLOG table.

Comment: Do you need to add that to your WHERE criteria -- didn't see that in your example: and EmpLog.Date IS NULL

Comment: Or you can try this one -- not sure why you're left joining and doing a not in -- either way, this removes it as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/519d7/3 -- Best of luck

Comment: i need this part `Select EmpLog.Date from EmpLog where EmpLog.EmpID = @EmpID` because there are different users.

Comment: @sgeddes that works perfectly! so this is my final select statement: `SELECT AllDates FROM cte left join EmpLog ON convert(varchar, AllDates, 101) = convert(varchar, EmpLog.Date, 101) left JOIN Holiday ON convert(varchar, AllDates, 101) = convert(varchar, Holiday.HolDate, 101)
    WHERE  DATENAME(dw, AllDates) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') 
    AND Holiday.HolDate IS NULL  AND DATENAME(dw, AllDates) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') AND convert(varchar, AllDates, 101) NOT IN (Select convert(varchar, EmpLog.Date, 101)from EmpLog where EmpLog.EmpID = 1)`

thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the @MyDate initialisation to:

```
set @MyDate = Convert(DATETIME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 121) + ' 00:00:00', 121);
```

Explanation: By doing this you make the @MyDate as a "midnight today", instead of "today with current time". That way it would better join with your tables.

Assumption: The dates in your holiday tables are stored as "midnight"

Comment: thanks for your answer. i think this is the part of the query that is not workng because i tried to remove and put this query and nothing happens, same output. "AllDates NOT IN (Select EmpLog.Date from EmpLog where EmpLog.EmpID = 1)and Holiday.HolDate IS NULL"

Comment: Just run a simple select on both of your servers and compare result: select datepart(dw, getdate()), datename(dw, getname())

Comment: I know that, thanks. But what I asked is to run it on your both servers: 2008 and 2005. Please check that on both servers the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some differences between dates in 2008 and 2005.  You have to set your database compatibility.  See the following article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx